# How to prevent PyCharm from navigating into stubs?

Tags: pycharm

Usually, when left-clicking (while holding the command key, I am on Mac) into a module name in PyCharm, say numpy, PyCharm will navigate into that module's source file. However, for some module, say typing, PyCharm will resolve into a stub file, as shown in the screenshot: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNO7L.png). Is there any way to prevent PyCharm from navigating into the stub files? Besides the typing module, I have the same problem with Caffe, a deep learning module.